# Why is this if statement not fufilled when all the conditions are met?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
private int getNextNodesDirection(Pair<Integer, Integer> current, Pair<Integer, Integer> nextNode, Robot target) {
    System.out.println("current x:" + current.getSecond());
    System.out.println("current y:" + current.getFirst());
    System.out.println("next x:" + nextNode.getSecond());
    System.out.println("next y:" + nextNode.getFirst());

    if (target.getCurrentDirection().equals(IWorld.Direction.UP)) {
        //if y increases and x stays the same
       
        if (nextNode.getFirst() > current.getFirst() && nextNode.getSecond().equals(current.getFirst())) {
            return 0;
        }
        // if x increases and y stays the same
        else if (nextNode.getSecond() > current.getSecond() && nextNode.getFirst().equals( current.getFirst())) {
            return 1;
        }




while (index < endIndex){
        int fSteps = 0;
        int direction = getNextNodesDirection(nodeList.get(index), nodeList.get(index+1), target);
        if (direction == 1){
            cost+=1;
            target.handleCommand(new RightCommand());
        }
        else if (direction == 2){
            cost+=2;
            target.handleCommand(new RightCommand());
            target.handleCommand(new RightCommand());
        }
        else if (direction == 3){
            cost+=1;
            target.handleCommand(new LeftCommand());
        }
        while (direction == 0){
            fSteps += 1;
            cost+=fSteps;
            index+=1;
            if(nodeList.get(index).getSecond() == (end.getX()) && nodeList.get(index).getFirst() == end.getY()){
                break;
            }
            direction = getNextNodesDirection(nodeList.get(index), nodeList.get(index+1), target);
```

So when the program runs it enters into getNextNodesDirection and executes as expected but on the second time round, although all the conditions are fulfilled it just goes passed the statement. Why? I would like it to return 0 while `nextNode.getFirst()` is greater than `current.getFirst` and `nextNode.getSecond()` is equal to `current.getSecond()`

I've screenshotted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erAUR.jpg) in IntelliJ, while debugging, you can clearly see that y is increasing and x staying the same yet it passes the "fulfilled" condition and carries on. Why?

The language is Java 11, OS is Debian on a virtual machine.

Comment: `nextNode.getSecond().equals(current.getFirst())` is false. Did you meant `nextNode.getSecond().equals(current.getSecond())`?

Comment: Without going into deails, I would like to recommend you to refactore the code. For example extract boolean expression so that you can replace `nextNode.getFirst() > current.getFirst()` by `isNextNodeGreater`. This will make you code much more readable and the additional benefit is, that you can see the result of the condition in your debugger.

Comment: @talex thank you very much, can't believe I missed this. Was late in the day.